# Asp.Net Webapi OData V4 Enum Key Support

Tags: asp.net, enums, odata

I implemented a ASP.Net Webapi (V4.6) with OData V4 support.
My Controllers are inherited from ODataController and i use the standard Json Serializer.

Some of my entities have enum fields and i want serialize the enum keys and not the correponded value. I am using OData with Asp.Net.WebApi.OData v5.7 and can't find a suitable solution.
Have anybody a idea to implement this?

Entity class:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    #region Properties     

    public int Id { get;set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public ProjectStatus Status { get; set; }
    public double EstimatedCost { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public enum ProjectStatus
{
    New = 10,
    Active = 20,
    Paused = 30,
    Finished = 40,
}
```

The result after serialization is :
{
"Id":1,"StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,**"Status":"Active"**,"EstimatedCost":0.0
}

Is it possible to serialize the Key ("Status":"20") from an enum and not the value, because the result after serialization is : "Status":"Active".

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm facing a similar one and would be really grateful if you could help me.